# Fastest way to construct sparse block matrix in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, array-broadcasting

I want to construct a matrix of shape `(N,2N)` in Python.

I can construct the matrix as follows

```py
import numpy as np 

N = 10 # 10,100,1000, whatever

some_vector = np.random.uniform(size=N) 

some_matrix = np.zeros((N, 2*N))

for i in range(N):
    some_matrix[i, 2*i] = 1
    some_matrix[i, 2*i + 1] = some_vector[i]
```

So the result is a matrix of mostly zeros, but where on row `i`, the `2*i` and `2*i + 1` columns are populated.

Is there a faster way to construct the matrix without the loop? Feels like there should be some broadcasting operation...

Edit: There have been some very fast, great answers! I am going to extend the question a touch to my actual use case.

Now suppose `some_vector` has a shape `(N,T)`. I want to construct a matrix of shape `(N,2*N,T)` analogously to the previous case. The naive approach is:

```py
N = 10  # 10,100,1000, whatever
T = 500 # or whatever

some_vector = np.random.uniform(size=(N,T)) 

some_matrix = np.zeros((N, 2*N,T))

for i in range(N):
    for t in range(T):
        some_matrix[i, 2*i,t] = 1
        some_matrix[i, 2*i + 1,t] = some_vector[i,t]
```

Can we extend the previous answers to this new case?

Comment: I have extended the question slightly. It is obvious how to extend the methods of Andrej Kesely to this new case, but I am just checking if anything changes with the inclusion of the extra dimension

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Variant 1

You can replace the loop with a broadcasting assignment, which interleaves the columns of an identity matrix with the columns of a diagonal matrix:

```
a = np.eye(N)
b = np.diag(some_vector)

c = np.empty((N, 2*N))
c[:, 0::2] = a
c[:, 1::2] = b
```

This is concise, but not optimal.  This requires allocating some unnecessary intermediate matrices (`a` and `b`), which becomes increasing expensive as `N` grows larges. This also involves performing random-access assignments to *every* position in `c`, instead of just the non-zero entries.

This may be faster or slower than the implementation in the question for different values of `N`.

#### Variant 2

Similar idea Variant 1, but only performs a single allocation and avoids unnecessary assignments to zero entries.

We create a single vector of size `2*N**2`, which essentially represents the rows of `some_matrix` concatenated with one another. The non-zero positions are populated using broadcasting assignments. We then create an `(N, 2*N)` view into this vector using [`np.ndarray.reshape`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.reshape.html#numpy.ndarray.reshape).

```
some_matrix = np.zeros(2 * n**2)

step = 2 * (n + 1)

some_matrix[::step] = 1
some_matrix[1::step] = some_vector
some_matrix = some_matrix.reshape(n, 2 * n)
```

#### Performance Comparison

For relatively small `N` (`N=100`):

- Variant 1 is about 40% faster than the Python loop (12 us vs 21 us)
- Variant 2 is about 80% faster than the Python loop (4 us vs 21 us)

For large `N` (`N=10_000`):

- Variant 1 is slower than the Python loop.
- Variant 2 is about 20% faster than the Python loop (10 us vs 13 us)

##### Setup:

```
import numpy as np


def original(n):
    some_vector = np.random.uniform(size=n)
    some_matrix = np.zeros((n, 2 * n))

    for i in range(n):
        some_matrix[i, 2 * i] = 1
        some_matrix[i, 2 * i + 1] = some_vector[i]


def variant_1(n):
    some_vector = np.random.uniform(size=n)

    a = np.eye(n)
    b = np.diag(some_vector)
    
    c = np.empty((n, 2*n))
    c[:, 0::2] = a
    c[:, 1::2] = b


def variant_2(n):
    some_vector = np.random.uniform(size=n)
    
    some_matrix = np.zeros(2 * n**2)
    step = 2 * (n + 1)
    some_matrix[::step] = 1
    some_matrix[1::step] = some_vector
    some_matrix = some_matrix.reshape(n, 2*n)
```

##### Timing at `N=100`:

```
%timeit -n1000  original(100)
21.1 µs ± 2.22 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

%timeit -n1000  variant_1(100)
12.2 µs ± 431  ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

%timeit -n1000  variant_2(100)
4.37 µs ± 21.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

##### Timing at `N=1_000`

```
%timeit -n100  original(1_000)
631 µs ± 98.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit -n100  variant_1(1_000)
5.24 ms ± 157 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit -n100  variant_2(1_000)
408 µs ± 12.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

##### Timing at `N=10_000`

```
%timeit -n100  original(10_000)
12.6 ms ± 225 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit -n100  variant_2(10_000)
10.1 ms ± 109 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Tested using Python 3.10.12 and Numpy v1.26.0.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach:

```py
some_matrix = np.zeros(N * 2 * N)

a = np.arange(0, N * 2 * N, 2 * N) + np.arange(0, N) * 2

some_matrix[a] = 1
some_matrix[a + 1] = some_vector

print(some_matrix.reshape((N, 2 * N)))
```

---

Benchmark (including [numba](/questions/tagged/numba) versions):

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import perfplot
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from numba import njit, prange

plt.rcParams["figure.autolayout"] = True
np.random.seed(0)


def get_matrix(some_vector):
    N = len(some_vector)
    some_matrix = np.zeros((N, 2 * N))

    for i in range(N):
        some_matrix[i, 2 * i] = 1
        some_matrix[i, 2 * i + 1] = some_vector[i]
    return some_matrix


def get_matrix_brian_1(some_vector):
    N = len(some_vector)

    a = np.eye(N)
    b = np.diag(some_vector)

    c = np.empty((N, 2 * N))
    c[:, 0::2] = a
    c[:, 1::2] = b
    return c


def get_matrix_brian_2(some_vector):
    n = len(some_vector)

    some_matrix = np.zeros(2 * n**2)

    step = 2 * (n + 1)

    some_matrix[::step] = 1
    some_matrix[1::step] = some_vector
    return some_matrix.reshape(n, 2 * n)


def get_matrix_andrej(some_vector):
    N = len(some_vector)
    some_matrix = np.zeros(N * 2 * N)

    a = np.arange(0, N * 2 * N, 2 * N) + np.arange(0, 2 * N, 2)

    some_matrix[a] = 1
    some_matrix[a + 1] = some_vector

    return some_matrix.reshape((N, 2 * N))


@njit
def get_matrix_andrej_numba(some_vector):
    N = len(some_vector)
    some_matrix = np.zeros((N, 2 * N))

    for i in range(N):
        some_matrix[i, 2 * i] = 1
        some_matrix[i, 2 * i + 1] = some_vector[i]
    return some_matrix


@njit(parallel=True)
def get_matrix_andrej_numba_parallel(some_vector):
    N = len(some_vector)
    some_matrix = np.zeros((N, 2 * N))

    for i in prange(N):
        some_matrix[i, 2 * i] = 1
        some_matrix[i, 2 * i + 1] = some_vector[i]
    return some_matrix


# compile numba functions
get_matrix_andrej_numba(np.array([1, 2, 3]))
get_matrix_andrej_numba_parallel(np.array([1, 2, 3]))


perfplot.show(
    setup=lambda n: np.random.uniform(size=n),
    kernels=[
        get_matrix,
        get_matrix_andrej,
        get_matrix_brian_1,
        get_matrix_brian_2,
        get_matrix_andrej_numba,
        get_matrix_andrej_numba_parallel,
    ],
    labels=[
        "get_matrix",
        "get_matrix_andrej",
        "get_matrix_brian_1",
        "get_matrix_brian_2",
        "get_matrix_andrej_numba",
        "get_matrix_andrej_numba_parallel",
    ],
    n_range=[10, 50, 100, 250, 500, 1000, 2_500, 5_000],
    xlabel="N",
    logx=True,
    logy=True,
)
```

Creates this graph:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Given that most elements of this array are zero, you could save a lot of CPU and memory if you only stored the non-zero elements.

You could do this with either [SciPy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html) or [Sparse](https://sparse.pydata.org/en/stable/). (SciPy has the advantage of supporting more types of operations. Sparse has the advantage of supporting 3D arrays.)

2D example:

```
import scipy.sparse


def get_matrix_njo(some_vector):
    N = len(some_vector)
    data = np.empty(N * 2)
    data[0::2] = 1
    data[1::2] = some_vector
    cols = np.arange(N * 2, dtype='int32')
    rows = cols // 2
    some_matrix = scipy.sparse.coo_matrix((data, (rows, cols)), shape=(N, 2*N))
    return some_matrix
```

Whether this is faster or slower depends on whether you have to convert the sparse result of this to a dense matrix.

If you do convert to dense, then it is somewhat slower than the other two answers.

If you can keep it as a sparse matrix, it is much is faster than the other answers for large matrices, as it runs in O(N) time and space, where the other answers need O(N<sup>2</sup>) time and space.

Next, I looked at how to extend this to a 3D array. SciPy does not support 3D arrays, but another package, [Sparse](https://sparse.pydata.org/en/stable/index.html), does.

3D example:

```
from sparse import COO

def make_matrix_3d_njo(some_vector):
    N, T = some_vector.shape
    number_non_zero_entries = 2 * N * T
    data = np.zeros((N, 2 * T))
    coords = np.zeros((3, 2 * N, T), dtype='int32')
    c1 = np.arange(2 * N, dtype='int32')
    c0 = c1 // 2
    c2 = np.arange(T, dtype='int32')
    coords[0] = c0[:, None]
    coords[1] = c1[:, None]
    coords[2] = c2[None, :]
    coords = coords.reshape(3, number_non_zero_entries)
    data[:, :T] = 1
    data[:, T:] = some_vector
    data = data.flatten()
    return COO(coords, data, shape=(N, 2 * N, T))
```